# how to remove this error NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, ngfor

I have a function in my component as

```js
  missionSelected(event){
    this.category = event.option.value.children;
    console.log(this.category);
  }
```

This console log i am getting as:

```js
    (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

But as i am using this variable in my template as:

```html
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let cat of category" [value]="cat">
        <div>{{cat.name}}</div>
    </mat-list-option>
```

This one giving me error as:

```js
    find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'.
NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

I tried to reinitialize the same object in array variable but i am getting same error. Many ways i tried but not getting proper solution.

[image: adding console screenshot]

Comment: Please provide your html code and ts, as the code you have provided, seems to be fine.

Comment: what is there inside (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: can you elaborate what you got in the console, (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}] may be a mock data would help us to figure out?

Comment: can you please console.log(this.category[0]);

Comment: yes `{path: "/home/rajesh/geospace/GIS", name: "GIS", children: Array(4), size: 18502537, type: "directory"}
children: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
name: "GIS"
path: "/home/rajesh/geospace/GIS"
size: 18502537
type: "directory"
__proto__: Object`

Comment: Add {{ category | json }} in your template and see what its outputting.

Answer (score 2):

You either need to check in the template if the array is defined

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="category">
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let cat of category" [value]="cat">
    <div>{{cat.name}}</div>
  </mat-list-option>
</ng-container>
```

or initialize the array in the definition.

```js
category: Array<any> = [];
```

#### Update: `keyvalue` pipe

I am not sure if you're actually looping through an array. If in any case it's an object, you could use [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe with the `*ngFor` directive.

```html
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let cat of category | keyvalue" [value]="cat.value">
  <div>{{cat.key}}</div>
  <div>{{cat.value}}</div>
</mat-list-option>
```

Comment: From one of your other comments, you say the definition is `category: [];`. That wrongfully defines the variable to be of type `[]`, not the JS `Array`. It needs to be `category: Array<any>`.

Comment: As per your recommendation  i changed the definition from  category: []; to category: Array<any> = []; but getting same error

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your console log. Also please check if it works with the `keyvalue` pipe as mentioned in the update. If so, they the response is actually an object.

Comment: added screenshots of my console in question section . if i am using keyvalue pipe i am getting another error as ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngForOf: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]'. Current value: 'ngForOf: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the initial value of `category`. Have you initialized it to `[]` for example? If the initial value is null or other object `*ngFor` can't work with it as the message says.

Comment: yes i have already declare that in my component as category: [];

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all answer but i only was doing the mistake here: in my template i am using reference #category which is same as my category variable as shown below:

```
<mat-selection-list #category [multiple]="false">           
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let cat of category" [value]="cat.value">
<mat-icon mat-list-icon>folder</mat-icon>             
<div mat-line>{{cat.name}}</div>          
</mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

I just changed that reference name from #category to #reffer and it worked.....